# How can I run IDTool in 3ds Max after installation of that IDTool?

Tags: macros, 3dsmax, maxscript

I have installed IDTool on my PC.
But I don't know how I can run that tool.
I already installed 3Ds Max 2023 and the version of IDTool is 2.3.4.
I want to run IDTool on 3Ds Max.

After installation of IDTool, I could see IBS_IDTool.mcr file in macroscripts folder.
I thought this was a script file, I tried to run this script on scripting editor.
But I could not see GUI.
I want to see GUI by running this script.
Or, I want to know how I can run ID Tool.

Thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know this is macro.
There are two kinds of scripts in 3ds Max.
First is maxscript(extension is .ms) and second is macroscript(extension is .mcr).
So, I need several macro commands to run macroscript.

```
macros.load "F:\3d max script\3d max Script\macros"
macros.list()
macros.run 27613
```

Thank you for your considering.